# Select link from table using single selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, selenium

I wrote selector like this

```
jQuery("td:contains('test')").parent("tr").find("a")
```

I want to click link in table. It works great, however I'd like to use it as selenium selector.

Selenium supports jQuery selectors, but they have to be one liners, for example

```
selenium.click("jquery=a:contains('test')");
```

How to convert my selector into one liner selector? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `jQuery("tr:has(td:contains('test')) a")`